# Ruby: How to convert ipv6 uo address to ipv4 ip address?

Tags: ruby, ipv6, ipv4

It is easy to convert ipv4 to ipv6 with ipv4_mapped. But how about the other around?

I did not find a way to do that in IpAddr documentation.

Comment: IP doesn't work that way, does it? You can encapsulate an IPv4 address within IPv6, it's part of the specification, but the reverse requires an IPv4 to IPv6 proxy.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols. There is a representation of IPv4 addresses in IPv6 notation, but that doesn't mean you can just convert addresses between the different protocols. They are different and have to be handled separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's important to understand that it's impossible to convert most IPv6 addresses to IPv4 addresses (for several reasons, the most obvious being that there's no way to fit a 128-bit number into 32 bits). The only IPv6 addresses that can be converted to IPv4 are ones that are mapped from IPv4 address (such as those produced by `IPAddr#ipv4_mapped`). For that, we have [`IPAddr#native`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-native):

```
require "ipaddr"

ip = IPAddr.new("192.168.2.128")
ipv6 = ip.ipv4_mapped
puts ipv6.native
# => 192.168.2.128
```